# Using Ansible Clouldformation module to provision a CoreOS cluster

Tags: ansible, aws-cloudformation, coreos

I am new to Ansible and I am not sure what my host file look like if I want to provision the cluster from my local. My yaml file is as follows:

```
---
- hosts: coreos
  tasks:
    - name: Automation CoreOS Cluster
      action: cloudformation >
        stack_name="automation_ansible_coreos_cluster" state=present
        region=us-east-1 disable_rollback=true
        template=files/coreos-stable-pv.template
      args:
        template_parameters:
          InstanceType: m1.small
          ClusterSize: 3
          DiscoveryURL: 'https://discovery.etcd.io/<val>'
          KeyPair: Automation
      tags:
        Stack: ansible-cloudformation-coreos
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: coreos
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: Automation CoreOS Cluster
    cloudformation: stack_name='automation-ansible-coreos-cluster' state=present region='us-east-1'         disable_rollback=true template='files/coreos-stable-pv.template'
    args:
      template_parameters:
        InstanceType: t1.micro
        ClusterSize: 3
        DiscoveryURL: 'https://discovery.etcd.io/<val>'
        KeyPair: Automation
    register: stack
    tags:
        Stack: ansible-cloudformation-coreos
```

Host file:

```
[coreos]
host1
host2
host3
```

Answer (score 2):

convert playbook to look like the following:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Automation CoreOS Cluster
    cloudformation: stack_name='automation_ansible_coreos_cluster' state=present region='us-east-1' disable_rollback=true template='files/coreos-stable-pv.template'
    args:
      template_parameters:
        InstanceType: m1.small
        ClusterSize: 3
        DiscoveryURL: 'https://discovery.etcd.io/<val>'
        KeyPair: Automation
    register: stack
    tags:
      Stack: ansible-cloudformation-coreos
```

Setting host to `localhost` and connection to `local` will resolve your issue, with the addition of `gather_facts: false` will skip gathering information from the inventory file and continue to provision your machines which resolves the need to look for machines (that have not been created as yet!)

Also, you will need AWS user credentials with enough access to perform the operation in question